# Strange slow performance in mysql replication

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, replication, database-performance

I have MySQL (MariaDB 10.1.27) master that hold ~1900 databases. Total dbs size ~100GB
Used InnoDB engine with innodb_file_per_table = 1

I'm going to setup two slaves for this server (MariaDB 10.1.27).
Both slaves with identical hardware like master.
master was stopeed at midnight, was made backup from /var/lib/mysql with tar
and this tar was transferred and extracted on two separated servers.

One slave setted up fast, and catched up master (1 day delay) in ~1 hour.
In time of catching up, I got 100% CPU usage (LA 3-4) with log of disk activity (~20%wa)

Second slave has some strange problem with replication performance.
After setup it catching up master more than 2 days. And procees finished 20% only.
current show slave status:

```
show slave status\Gshow processlist;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: XXXXXXXXXX
                  Master_User: XXXXXXXX
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysqld-bin.000572
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 524619108
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000004
                Relay_Log_Pos: 916671538
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysqld-bin.000571
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: apsc.%,billing.%,information_schema.%,performance_schema.%,horde.%,mysql.%,phpmyadmin_gmRJC4rn_tom.%,psa.%,roundcubemail.%,sitebuilder5.%
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 916671245
              Relay_Log_Space: 1598365917
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 24730
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 111
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos:
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

No serious activity present on CPU and on disk (see top screen later)

```
======
top - 03:36:36 up 114 days, 12:26,  9 users,  load average: 1.82, 1.86, 1.89
Tasks: 364 total,   1 running, 362 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.5%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.7%id, 4.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32993560k total, 32271192k used,   722368k free,   625464k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,   229512k used,  3964784k free, 23100280k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13809 mysql      1 -19 6819m 5.8g 7332 S 8.9 18.5 132:12.33 mysqld
======
```

As I see, all bin logs transferred from master to slave currently, 
but slave have slow performance in applying this logs to dbs.

In slow query log (2 seconds limit) I have no any records.

Googling problem not help. Already tried:

```
skip-name-resolve

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT

#move innodb logs to SSD
nnodb_log_group_home_dir=/var/lib/mysql_logs
```

Setup multithreaded replication attempt (2 and 4 threads) was failed, because slowing down process more that current state. Slave got increasing lag (Seconds_Behind_Master in show slave status)

Please advice me what can be source of problem and what can be made to make replication faster.

Comment: "Second _master_ has some strange..." -- Perhaps you meant "slave"?

Comment: Yes, you right. Corrected question

Comment: Diff the my.cnf files.